# On adding jquery unobtrusive ajax script file controllers action runs two times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I wanted to add user Ajax.Actionlink in my application and to make that work I had to add

```
jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js
```

Now that I have added it, there are weird things happening.
This is the order in which I load the js files

```
   bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js",
                 "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"));
```

the layout page loads this js files in the same order that I have mentioned
So my _layout page has

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")      
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Kendo")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/toastr")
```

Now when I submit ajax form from view

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddAttendeeInternalAddressBook", "Attendee", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "doneInternalAddressBook" }))
{
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
     @Html.ValidationSummary()

    <div class="form-group">             
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SelectedAddressBookPerson.Email, new {@class = "form-control", PlaceHolder = "Search in AddressBook..." }) &nbsp; &nbsp;               
        <input type="submit" id="btnAddressBook" class="btn btn-default" value="Add>>">           
    </div>
}
```

This controller's method runs twice

```
public ActionResult AddAttendeeInternalAddressBook(CreateAppointmentSelectPersons internalAddressbookPerson)
{
    bool result = _attendeeRepository.CheckIfAttendeeExists(internalAddressbookPerson.SelectedAddressBookPerson.AppointmentId, internalAddressbookPerson.SelectedAddressBookPerson.Email);
    if (!result)
    {
        _attendeeRepository.AddInternalAddressBookAttendee(
        internalAddressbookPerson.SelectedAddressBookPerson.AppointmentId,
        internalAddressbookPerson.SelectedAddressBookPerson.FirstName,
        internalAddressbookPerson.SelectedAddressBookPerson.LastName,
        internalAddressbookPerson.SelectedAddressBookPerson.Email);
    }

    return Json(new { AttendeeExists = result, ErrorMessage = "Person already exists in your list" });  
}
```

So when I put breakpoint on this action's first line and post the form, the first line

```
bool result = _attendeeRepository.CheckIfAttendeeExists(internalAddressbookPerson.SelectedAddressBookPerson.AppointmentId, internalAddressbookPerson.SelectedAddressBookPerson.Email);
```

gets executed twice. Then the if statement gets executed twice then the repository method gets called twice.

So basically all the lines are being executed twice. And the person is is being added to my database twice.

But when I remove the line (not load)

```
  "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"
```

everything is fine.
The action in controller gets executed once (the way it should).

I also have UnobtrusiveJavascriptEnabled to true

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
```

**Question:**

Can anyone explain what is happening.

Why are controller's action's each line being executed twice when I submit ajax forms?

Comment: Verify is you have set UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled=true when including jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js. See http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-ajax.html section "Enabling Unobtrusive Ajax"

Comment: I have set unobtrusivejavascriptenabled to true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be added the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` more then once in your application. So that it might run the controller twice

Comment: Didn't even realize that. Thanks for the reminder. Was a great great help. Saved my day!

Comment: In an MVC project this was the correct answer for me, I had mistakenly included the bundle in the layout file and then in the specific view.  I meant to only include in the view that required the ajax.  Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Nice one, I had done the exact same thing and spent days scratching my head because of it